# Compile a file into a library and access it, but not as a resource

Tags: .net, resources

Our software does have a very old, and for today's possibilities probably a very strange way to be translatable. The reason for that is probably, that the translatable strings are coming from very different places, like VB6 dlls, .NET dlls, Access forms/reports, metadata... and so on. Well, it is like it is.

In general there's a tool that extracts all translatable strings from the different sources and converts them to a format that can be translated with a professional translation tool. After that the translations are converted back to a format that the software can use, as soon as someone wants it to be translated.

For .NET dlls the tool extracts all resources from the dll and puts them after translation in separate text files, and if the software needs to be translated it reads the translated resources from these text files instead.

Now to my problem... I want to put a xml file as resource into one of the dlls and this xml file shouldn't be extracted for translation and it shouldn't be read from the text file containing the translated strings.

But right now, exactly that happens, the extractor extracts the contents of this xml file for translation and the translated software looks for that xml file in the translated text files.

Of course I could try to fix that problem by changing the extractor to skip file resources and to fix the part of the software which decides where to look for a resource. But this part of our software isn't exactly my expertise.

So I thought you maybe know of a way to put the xml file into the dll and access it without it being a resource?

What's the "Build Action" setting of a resource file good for? Right now the "Build Action" for my resource file is "Resource". What do all the other "Build Action" settings do (like "Embedded Resource", "Content", "AdditionalFiles", "ApplicationDefinition", ...)? Would it help to do some research in that direction?

Comment: How is the XML file read from the resource? One (somewhat kludgy) work-around might be to convert the XML file into a constant.

Comment: It is read the usual way `Properties.Resources.<ResourceName>`. The xml file needs gto be changed from time to time. This might be difficult in a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying it helped for my case, to remove the file resource and add the xml file with "EmbeddedResource" as "Build Action" to the project.

After that I could get the content of the xml file in code like this:

```
string xmlFile;

//to find out the full name of the embedded resource use the following line
//string[] resourceNames = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

using (System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(<FullResourceName>), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xmlFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
```